# Repartition the disk without losing OS

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, partitioning

I have a 5 year old PC with single partition on 40GB harddisk (10GB free) and widows XP installed. I want to create another partition and install Ubuntu on it. Is it possible to re-partition the disk without losing the windows XP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI

First I would suggest that you use WUBI Installer. Here: http://wubi-installer.org/

What it lets you do is install ubuntu without partition your drive. And you can uninstall it like any other program in your windows XP OS.

Or if you really want to partition your drive use Easus Partition Manager. http://www.partition-tool.com/
You can divide your drive without losing your Data. :)

You should probably back up just in case though

Comment: Partition tool worked without any issue. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to here! Have fun with Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I second the use of Wubi, as installing Ubuntu also means installing Grub which could make things interesting if it doesn't pick up the XP install.

I would recommend gparted if you really want to repartition your disk: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Comment: gparted is good too, however you have to burn it to a CD and then Boot from it and then partition your drive from there. If you use easus then all you have to do is install it like any piece of software and run it.

Comment: Nathan, I think you beat me by 8 seconds!

Comment: @thegretspot that is true. I have just had personal success with gparted.

Answer (score 1):

[gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to do a proper install of Ubuntu, there is a partition tool as part of the installer; you don't have to do it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

First before following anything, just mention: BACKUP.

1 option: Put your Ubuntu cd into your drive when youre logged into XP. You should get the WUBI installer, which lets you install ubuntu in the C:\Ubuntu. Pretty easy, nothing hard. Still if you really want to repartition use EASUS partition manager, have been using it and i have to say it's quite good. If you do not want to use any kind of program, use a cd; like GParted.