# How do I partition a disk with Windows XP already installed?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning

I have Windows XP Professional on a hard disk. Is it possible to partition this disk so I can install Linux in a dual boot configuration?

Comment: Not a programming question, but most live CD's will have a tool that does this for you.

Comment: Very carefully.

Comment: @music2myear the tools like Partition wizard and Easeus will do the good work mostly not losing data, if you haven't a misfortune.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try ubuntu it offers this as an option during the standard install.  If you want to do it manually select the try ubuntu from the live CD then use gparted to do it.  Obviously this is only possible if you have sufficient free space on your hard drive.  I'd also recommend defragmenting before you start.

With Unity (standard in ubuntu 11.04) you'll find this by just pressing the windows key and typing gparted.  If you use and older livecd it's in the system menu under administration.

Comment: Ubuntu's partition manager can and does do this without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [Easus Partition Manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/). I have used the tool more than once and it has not failed me anytime. There are more options/answers on this topic in below link which you may want to look.

[repartition-the-disk-without-losing-os](https://superuser.com/questions/60427/repartition-the-disk-without-losing-os/60447#60447)

Comment: Just beat me by 1 Min.............

Comment: +1 for Easeus, I love that tool, always works and always does a good job, so far at least. Additional bonus, it is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable with partitioning wubi is an easy way to install ubuntu over a windows install http://wubi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html). Its also available in freeware version and do the a lots of your work of partition without losing data.